Terraform Azure Data Factory parameters
I'm trying to pass a parameter to a ADF in Terraform. I'm trying to add it to azurerm_data_factory_dataset_json so we have something like this:

I was trying different approaches how to add this parameter but none of them worked.
Here's latest piece of code:
     resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_json" "reports_json" {
   name                = "mydk-adf-dataset-reports-json-${var.regional_mapping[var.region]}-${var.env}"
   data_factory_id     = azurerm_data_factory.reports_adf.id
   linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage.reports_ls_storage.name

   parameters = {
     name = "tempFile",
     type = "String"
   }

   azure_blob_storage_location {
     container = "reports"
     path      = "temp/"
     filename  = "@dataset().tempFile"
     dynamic_filename_enabled = true
   }
   encoding = "UTF-8"
 }

The error I'm getting is:

How to properly add String parameter to ADF? Thanks!

Please post your Terraform code for the azurerm_data_factory_dataset_json resource.

I've added code to post

To pass parameters to an Azure Data Factory (ADF) dataset in Terraform, you need to define the parameters within the dataset configuration. Here's how you can modify your Terraform code to include the parameters:
resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_json" "reports_json" {

name                = "mydk-adf-dataset-reports-json-${var.regional_mapping[var.region]}-${var.env}"
data_factory_id     = azurerm_data_factory.reports_adf.id
linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage.reports_ls_storage.name
parameters = {
}
